# Im trying to change the button properties on click in android studio but it unfortunately stops the app

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash

My button `onClickListener` code:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
});
```

and it says

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ashishsolankar.fragmentstudy/ashishsolankar.fragmentstudy.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

How do I solve the error?

Comment: As the error says it seems that the button is null, if you can't figure out why, please post the content of your onCreate method and the xml layout you set as content view.

Comment: post your full code... let me check

Answer (score 0):

Your Button b1 is null. i.e. it has no reference to your button.

You have to get the reference to your Button before accessing it, like this

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

where my_button is the id you have given in xml for the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to avoid `null` exception:

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //change button id here
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
});
```